# Can't apply to any job

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I was applying to a few jobs, and after writing on the Dialog box my cover letter, it returns this error:

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
>   while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded
>   and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional
>   information about this error, do so at our feedback site,
>   meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: This should be resolved, would you try it once more?

Comment: Thank you very much, it is solved. I have just send an application to the same job. Thanks again.